# Is this Flutter (Dart) code robust re "async" usage or are futher null checks required?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-async, flame

Is the following Flutter (using Flame package too) code robust in the sense that, is there a risk "prefs" may not be available during "update" and further checks and balances should be put in?   Suggested code change to make it robust?

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flame/components.dart';
import 'package:flame/flame.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class LightComponent extends SpriteComponent  {
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    
    LightComponent() : super.fromImage(Vector2(404/4,406/4), Flame.images.fromCache('jupiter_404×406.png'),)
      
    Future<void> onLoad() async {
        prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    }
    
    void render(Canvas c) {
        super.render(c);
    }
    
    void update(double t) {
        super.update(t);
        bool showWindow = prefs.getBool('showWindow');  // <== IS THIS OK, OR IS THERE Pref == null potential issue to cover???
        // etc 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The engine waits for `onLoad()` to be done before it adds the component to the update loop, so your code is the preferred way to do initialization of things that need to be loaded within components. So since `update` won't be called on the component before `onLoad()` has finished, your code should be safe without any extra checks inside of `update`.

Comment: thanks - just checking, you mean including async calls completed too no doubt?

Comment: Since you are using `await` in `onLoad` the Future will not complete until `prefs` have been assigned. :)

Answer (score 1):

you can make it a global variable and initialize in your main and use it everywhere.

```
SharedPreferences storage;
Future<Null> main()async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  storage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  runApp(App());
}
```

I too do this for my flame projects.

Comment: ok thanks @Deepak - and do you then just get state for your Flame components within the vaious component files directly from "storage.getInt('xxx')" then I guess?   Do you set state (e.g. setInt) in the same fashion, or do you route back through a business/model layer out of curiousity?

Comment: oh also - you know how Global variables are kind of frowned upon - is this ok in this case?

Comment: for my understanding knowing how to make my posted code robust would still be good

Comment: yes you can set the int and fetch int also as you do in general and i think it is good if you are using it multiple times.